# How to set travel mode of google directions api dynamically in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I am trying to update the travel mode dynamically based on the selected radio buttons.

I have read the documentations of the directions api and have tried the following.

```
class Transport extends React.Component {
  state={
    origin: '',
    destination: '',
    directions: '',
    mode: 'DRIVING'
  }

  setDirections(){
    const DirectionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

      DirectionsService.route({
        origin: this.state.origin,
        destination: this.state.destination,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[this.state.mode]
      }, (result, status) => {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          this.setState({
            directions: result,
          });
        } else {
          console.error(`error fetching directions ${result}`);
          alert('Selected mode of transport is not available for the for the trip!');
        }
      });
  }

  showPlaceDetails(place) {
    let destination = sessionStorage.getItem('city');
    destination=destination.replace(/\+/g, ' ');
    console.log(destination);
    let origin = place.address_components[0].long_name.toString();
    try{
        origin+= ' ' + place.address_components[2].long_name.toString();
    }catch(e){}
    console.log(origin);

    this.setState(() => ({origin, destination}));

    this.setDirections();
}

onModeChange = (e) =>{
  const mode = e.target.value;
  console.log(mode);

  this.setState(() => ({mode}));

  this.setDirections();
}

   render() {
   const GoogleMapExample = withGoogleMap(props => (
      <GoogleMap
        defaultCenter = { { lat: 40.756795, lng: -73.954298 } }
        defaultZoom = { 13 }
      >
      {this.state.directions && <DirectionsRenderer directions={this.state.directions} />}
      </GoogleMap>
   ));
   return(
      <div>
        <div className='travel-details-container'>
          <div>
            <CitySuggestionBar onPlaceChanged={this.showPlaceDetails.bind(this)} />
            <div>
            <label htmlFor="driving">Driving</label>
            <input type="radio" name="transport-type" id="driving" value="DRIVING" 
            onChange={this.onModeChange} defaultChecked />
            <label htmlFor="transit">Bus/Train</label>
            <input type="radio" name="transport-type" id="transit" value="TRANSIT"
            onChange={this.onModeChange} />
            <label htmlFor="air">Airways</label>
            <input type="radio" name="transport-type" id="air" value="AIRWAYS"
            onChange={this.onModeChange} />
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <GoogleMapExample
          containerElement={ <div style={{ height: `500px`, width: '100%' }} /> }
          mapElement={ <div style={{ height: `100%` }} /> }
        />
      </div>
   );
   }
};
```

I have set the default mode to DRIVING in the state and the default radio checked is also DRIVING. However, when I change it to Bus/Train it still appears to be driving on the map. But, the most confusing things is when I switch back to driving the map now updates to Transit and the mode in the state  is driving.

Please Help!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely due to `setState` being asynchronous as described in the [State and Lifecycle documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). By calling `this.setDirections()` immediately following `this.setState`, `this.state.mode` will have the old state value until the asynchronous update completes. To address this, `setState` takes a second argument for a callback function that will run after the state update completes (see [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)). You can use this like `this.setState({ mode }, () => this.setDirections())`. Alternatively, you could use `componendDidUpdate` and check if any dependent values changed and then call `this.setDirections()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can change travel mode dynamically using JavaScript. Please check code as below:

In HTML, give selection box as below:

```
<select class="form-control" id="mode">
  <option value="">Select Mode</option>
  <option value="WALKING">Walking</option>
  <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
  <option value="BICYCLING">Bicycling</option>
  <option value="TRANSIT">Transit</option>
</select>
```

In initMap() function of JavaScript, add as below:

```
  document.getElementById("mode").addEventListener("change", () => {
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer);
  });
```

Here, calculateAndDisplayRoute is a separate function in JavaScript:

```
function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer)
{
  var selectedMode = document.getElementById("mode").value;
  directionsService.route(
    {
      origin: Your Origin Values,
      destination: Your Destination Values,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode]
    },
    (response, status) => {
      if (status == "OK") {
        directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
      }
      else {
        window.alert("Directions request failed due to " + status);
      }
    }
  );
}
```